# Format IEnumerable<double> while displaying in a console

Tags: c#, performance, c#-4.0, ienumerable

I have to format a collection of doubles to 2 decimal places and display it in a console app by seperating it with a comma (,).

I have used the following:

```
var result = GetResults() //returns 1.234125, 3.56345, 6.43254

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",result)
```

However this does not format the values to 2 decimal places. I'm looking to display 1.23,3.56,6.43 to the console. Also the elements in "result" collection could range for a few 1000 doubles.So I'm looking for an optimized piece of code which will not involve any boxing and will take the least time to display itself to the console.

Thanks,
-Mike

Comment: The cost of printing to the console is vastly greater than the cost of any boxing.

Comment: What is return type of the `GetResults()` method?

Comment: @SLaks: on million objects boxing would make a difference

Comment: @sll: Yes, but the the time it takes to print 5 megabytes of text would _dwarf_ that time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String.Join(result.Select(d => d.ToString("0.00"))
```

[Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`Console` class effectively buffers all received data, so multiple `Console.Write` calls actually don't reduce permormance. Also you don't have to get all the text in one huge piece. So my answer is:

```
IEnumerable<double> result = new double[] { 1.1234, 2.2345, 3.3456 };
foreach (double item in result)
    Console.Write ("{0},", item.ToString("0.00"));
Console.WriteLine ();
```

Explicit `double.ToString` call allows to avoid unnecessary boxing. But I suggest you to compare performance in both ways before using more complicated one.

Also note that in some cultures a comma is already used as fractional separator.